# "How to correct syntax errors and defining errors when using a class"

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

I am working on a lab where we have to perform various matrix operations without using numpy. I have ran my code in the automated testing but am being told "name 'sub' is not defined". I am not sure what I need to change.

```
def sub(self, other):
    if self.cols != other.cols or self.rows != other.rows:
        return([])

    subtraction_matrix = []
    for i in range(self.cols):
        matrix3 = []
        for j in range(self.rows):
            subtraction = self.elements[i][j]- other.elements[i][j]

        matrix3.append(subtraction)

    return (subtraction_matrix)
```

Comment: What statement is triggering the error? Youre probably calling the function without an object

Comment: Im not sure which is the main error because when I run it on my computer it is fine but on the online submission page it says that sub is not defined.

Comment: Does the assignment ask for sub to be defined in the matrix object or does it ask for a matrix object to be passed in? My gut tells me that it's looking for a global function

Comment: This is what it said- "(Matrix, Matrix) -> Matrix
        Returns the result (as a new Matrix object) of subtract the second input Matrix to the
        first. Return an empty matrix if the matrices has mismatching sizes."

Comment: Yeah, your professor wants you to write the function outside of the class.

Comment: How can I declare it as a global function?

Comment: Move it outside the class, replace self with a different variable name, and return a newly constructed matrix from the result of the subtraction

Comment: Great Thanks so much